# Is it safe to repair inside wall and ceiling after ice dam?

Tags: ice

An ice dam at the intersection of a sloped roof and wall caused damage to the interior ceiling and wall. I cut through the surface of the ceiling and wall when it happened, to allow the collected water to drain, which took a couple days. At first a bunch rushed out, then it trickled out until a day or two after we had the dam fixed. When it was dry to the touch, I scraped/cut away all the damaged areas and applied joint compound with new tape, then used oil-based primer and painted.

Everything looks fine, but I'm worried about whether mold or some other bad stuff) could (or did) form behind the wall, either in the back of the drywall below where I repaired, or on the framing or insulation (probably R13 faced sheets).

Should I leave things as-is, or cut out a big section of drywall on the wall and ceiling and re-do it, or something else? Thanks!

Comment: hmmm hard to tell....tell us is the roof ventilated and how deep did you push your hand when you were checking if it is dry?

Comment: Hey, thanks. It's never easy, is it? Hehehe. The roof is right on top of the ceiling; there's no attic-like space above it. The wall sits about 1' inside the eave. I didn't actually reach in; the cuts I made were mostly just slices that took out the paint and a little drywall. I just pressed against the drywall to test for dryness. Thanks!

Comment: There is a good chance that there is some water still trapped inside, but depending on the layers of your roof this water could evaporate with higher temperatures. Since you haven't done it properly in the first place, leave it is, but look for the signs of humidity. Good thing you have a dry wall where you can easily spot traces of humidity.